# Magento2 unable to load theme error with Custom Admin theme

Tags: magento2, admin, error, theme, log

I have created new admin theme and used in my custom module di.xml file like below:

```
<type name="Magento\Theme\Model\View\Design">       
        <arguments>
            <argument name="themes" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="adminhtml" xsi:type="string">Newtheme/backend</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
```

but when i send any email from admin order, it throws error in system.log file like below:

```
Unable to load theme by specified key: '' [] []
```

Can anyone let me know what could be issue?i have done upgrade,compile,deploy and cache flush all the things.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to load theme by specified key: ''" Magento 2.3.4](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/302592/unable-to-load-theme-by-specified-key-magento-2-3-4)